# How to get the title and link to the previous and next post in php

Tags: php, post, permalinks

I'm new to PHP and learning by developing a little CRUD blog. My challenge now is how to get the title and link to the previous and next blog post after a user opens an article. This is to ensure easy navigation to the next and previous post without hitting the back button in order to select the next article.

The image below explains my write up.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uGfYM.png)

I have tried to query the database and use > than id or less than id to link to the next and previous articles which didn't work.

```
 <?php
    $previous = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE `posts`.`id` < $id";
    $next = "SELECT * FROM posts WHERE `posts`.`id` > $id";                      
    echo "<li><a href='{{url('post.php/' . $previous)}}'> Previous</a></li>";
    echo "<li><a href='{{url('post.php/' . $next)}}'> Next</a></li>";
?>
```

I actually wanted the previous and next links to the next and previous articles with their titles shown.

Comment: "higher than" $currentId would result in all articles. I am sure you only mean the closest next published article.

Comment: Exactly. The next in ascending order and the previous in descending order

Comment: So if you trust the very next ID is always the next one and the previous ID is always the previous one, you could calculate "where id = $thisID-1" for previous and "$thisID+1" for following.

Comment: Throwing error.

Comment: Add ORDER BY to make sure they are in the right order and LIMIT to show only the next highest post id: `"SELECT \`id\` FROM posts WHERE \`id\` < $id ORDER BY \`id\` DESC LIMIT 1";`

Comment: Also, where are you executing the query?

Comment: This is what its displaying   Previous
99 ORDER BY `posts`.`id` DESC LIMIT 1)}}'> Next

Comment: @tshimkus  in post.php

Comment: I mean, how is it not just showing the link as `<a href='post.php/"SELECT \`id\` FROM posts WHERE \`id\` < {id} ORDER BY \`id\` DESC LIMIT 1";'> Previous</a>`? Don't you need to execute a SQL query first to get the previous ID and then link to `<a href="post.php/123456"> Previous</a>`?

Answer (score 0):

```
#current blog post

$blog_id = 5;
$b_query=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE blog_id=:id AND blog_status=:status");
$b_query->execute(array(
    'id' => $blog_id,
    'status' => 1
));
$b_query_get=$b_query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

/* We check the existence of such data from the database. */
$single_post_control=$b_query->rowCount();
if($single_post_control == 0   ){
    echo "error";
    exit;
}

/* next post - previous post*/
$b_pre_nex=$conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM blogs WHERE   blog_id = (SELECT MIN(blog_id)  FROM blogs WHERE blog_id > :pre_nex_id AND blog_status=:pre_nex_status )  OR blog_id = (SELECT MAX(blog_id) FROM blogs WHERE blog_id < :pre_nex_id AND blog_status=:pre_nex_status) ");
$b_pre_nex->execute(array(
    'pre_nex_id' => $blog_id_get,
    'pre_nex_status' => 1
));

$control=$b_pre_nex->rowCount();
if($control == 0 || $control  > 3  ){
    echo "error";
    exit;
}

/* Here, we are splitting our previous and next posts separately.*/
$prev_post = $b_pre_nex->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$next_post = NULL;
while ( $rows = $b_pre_nex->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) {
    $next_post = $rows;
}
if(!isset($next_post)) {
    $next_post = null;
}


echo '<a href="#" style="float:left">'.$prev_post['blog_name'].'</a>';

echo '<a href="#" style="float:right">'.$next_post['blog_name'].'</a>';
```

maybe it can come in handy.

Answer (score -1):

```
/**
 * Rows per page
 */
$limit = 1;

// Find out how many items are in the table
$total = $db->get_total_count('cat_id', 'category', array('show_home_page' => 1, 'type_id' => 5, 'status' => 1));


// How many pages will there be
$pages = ceil($total / $limit);

// What page are we currently on?
$page = min($pages, filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'page', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, array(
    'options' => array(
        'default'   => 1,
        'min_range' => 1,
    ),
)));

// Calculate the offset for the query
$offset = ($page - 1)  * $limit;

// Some information to display to the user
$start = $offset + 1;
$end = min(($offset + $limit), $total);

// The "back" link
$prevlink = ($page > 1) ? '<a href="#prev" class="program_nav" data-id="'.($page - 1).'" title="Back"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>' : '<a href="#prev" class="disabled" title="Back"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i></a>';

// The "forward" link
$nextlink = ($page < $pages) ? '<a href="#next" class="program_nav" data-id="'.($page + 1).'" title="Next"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>' : '<a href="#next" class="disabled" title="Next"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></a>';


$total_query = 'SELECT COUNT(cat_id) FROM category WHERE show_home_page = 1 AND type_id = 5 AND status = 1';

$query = 'SELECT c.name, c.url FROM category as c WHERE c.show_home_page = 1 AND c.type_id = 5 AND c.status = 1 ORDER BY c.order ASC';

$programs = $db->get_table_custom($total_query, $query, true, $limit, $page);
```

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_total_count() on array in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\post.php:133 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\cms\post.php on line 133

Comment: This is what i got

Comment: This is the sample. You need to adapt to your own project.

Comment: A code dump with no explanation isn't entirely useful for an answer. Can you explain how this answers the question?